# How to set the sound setting so that you can "Listen to this device" (i.e an external microphone)

Tags: 11.04, sound, microphone

I have Ubuntu 11.04, and I would like to set my sound setting so that when I use my external microphone I can hear myself speak into the microphone as if it's a karaoke. I went to the sound setting, but it doesn't have the option to "listen to this device" as I can find in Windows. Is this an option in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

By choosing *"Sound Settings..."* from the drop down menu of the speaker icon in your top panel choose *Hardware* and select something like *"Analog Stereo **Duplex**"* from the *Profile* selection.

[image]

In case your microphone is recognized correctly you should be able to hear it through your local speakers.

Comment: I did that and I still cannot hear anything. Do I need to select the profile for my microphone device? When I did, there is not option for "Duplex."