# How to play music, coming from the microphone jack?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a USB device attached, which enumerates as a microphone. It streams some music, and I can easily record it with e.g. Audacity.

However, I want not to record it, but jsut listen on my headphones.

I have ALSA and Pulse Audio installed as usual. What is the best way to route the audio to my wishes?

Comment: Did you try a duplex profile: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73616/how-to-set-the-sound-setting-so-that-you-can-listen-to-this-device-i-e-an-ext?

Comment: @Takkat The duplex profile works only if the input and the output are part of the same sound card.

Answer (score 5):

I've picked this up some time ago. I hope it still works.

## How to load a loopback device in PulseAudio

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Then enter

```
pactl load-module module-loopback
```

(without sudo or any special root rights). Now you should hear what is coming from your AUX-in. If not then open your audio settings dialog and try to change your settings from there. You will find the additional loopback-device.

If this works good and you want to have it on each boot, do this

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "load-module module-loopback" >> /etc/pulse/default.pa'
```

If for some reason you want to mute the device

```
pactl set-source-mute 1 1
```

To un-mute it

```
pactl set-source-mute 1 0
```

I've used [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1324135#post8308073).

## Related

- Question: [Pulseaudio loopback unload audio output devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355082/pulseaudio-loopback-unload-audio-output-devices)

Comment: I don't see an additional device in the Sound Settings after applying the command. The only output at the terminal was `35`.

Comment: @Vorac use `pvaucontrol`. Not seeing a new device is normal, as a loopback is neither a sink nor a source. Also note that when you have multiple sources or sinks, you need to specifiy those. It's all documented [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/)

Answer (score 3):

First, open a terminal. You want to use `module-loopback` to send input from a source right back to a sink. @MadMike's answer is alright if you just have one sink and one source, but you'll most likely have more.

First, find the source you want to use, type `pactl list sources` to get a list of your sources. Then, find the sink you want to loop back the same way, using `pactl list sinks`. Remember the names, on a default setup (using `module-udev-detect`) these will look like `alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`

Next, you want to actually load [`module-loopback`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index62h3). This works the way @MadMike explained it, just be sure to include the sink and source names like this:

```
load-module module-loopback sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

If you put this into your system-wide configuration (`default.pa`), put it at the end and wrap it into `.fail` and `.nofail`, so Pulse will still start even when the device is unplugged.

```
.nofail
load-module module-loopback sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
.fail
```

When replugging the device, you'll also need to restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -K` (breaks active streams, restarts pulse immediately when autospawn is on)