UBUNTU 24.04 LTS Dummy Ouput Audio ALC1200 Realtek Audio
I've reinstalled ubuntu and windows to ensure it's not a hardware issue. The audio works without any issues on windows 10/11. I can't seem to get it working in ubuntu or any other linux distro.
aplay -l 

Ouputs this
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

alsamixer command
alsamixer main
pressing f6 and selecting option 2 HD-Audio Generic
HD-Audio Generic
I have pipewire and wireplumber installed. I've tried restarting, reloading both.
systemct; --user status wireplumber
● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; preset>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-07-23 12:40:09 EDT; 12min ago
   Main PID: 2069 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 38311)
     Memory: 8.9M (peak: 9.4M)
        CPU: 219ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/wirepl>
             └─2069 /usr/bin/wireplumber

Jul 23 12:40:09 aman-linux systemd[2049]: Started wireplumber.service - Multime>
Jul 23 12:40:09 aman-linux wireplumber[2069]: SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.ma>
Jul 23 12:40:09 aman-linux wireplumber[2069]: PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing >

systemctl --user status pipewire
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: e>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-07-23 12:40:09 EDT; 13min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 2064 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 38311)
     Memory: 6.4M (peak: 7.8M)
        CPU: 380ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewi>
             └─2064 /usr/bin/pipewire

Jul 23 12:40:09 aman-linux systemd[2049]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire M>

I'm not really sure how to solve this issue, I am very new to daily driving linux. I've mostly used wsl2 for development related.
Also here is my user group "uname : uname adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev users lpadmin"
Edit: lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio ouput
09:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:ab28]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:ab28]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
0b:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1043:87e9]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

edit #2: Spent a whole month on this (embarrassingly). I am leaving this for now, but I removed ubuntu and went back to windows. Seems it is better and works for now audio wise. I really wish I could make ubuntu work.

90% of times installing pavucontrol and playing with the configs there gets the sound fixed.

Okay, I rebooted, pavucontrol now sees it in config, enabled the starship/mattise hd audio controller. But all options are (unplugged)(unavailable)

check your connections/cables are they correctly connected?

Yeah I have headphone connected through usb c. Worked on windows without issues, but here not at all.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093343/usb-c-headphones-not-working-despite-being-listed-as-audio-device try it first and the links in there second

I tried a couple of pactl commands:
:~$ pactl list sinks short
34 auto_null PipeWire float32le 2ch 48000Hz SUSPENDED
:~$ pactl list sources short
34 auto_null.monitor PipeWire float32le 2ch 48000Hz SUSPENDED
